# How to display an alert on website when PHP incurs an error

Tags: php

Appologies in advance if this question has been asked allready, but I couldnt find anything related.

**My Problem**

I have two select boxes on a page where users can select two different teams and display their statistics / records against each other, however some of the teams have not played against each other at home or away, which result in PHP giving me an error.

Here is an example of what I am trying to say in the image below

[image]

*In the above example the Kings have never played against the Force Away*

If a selection like this happens **how can I let my users know that there has never been a fixture like the one selected, rather than showing them an ugly PHP error?**

Thank you in advance

Please note I also dont want to turn PHP error reporting off.

Comment: How could we guide you when there is no code...Use a conditional statement, check your post values, are they zero? great...dump a `$err = 'You cannot divide by zero'`, then echo that `$err` somewhere...

Comment: use if and else statement and show user error according to your requirement

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I did not feel it was necessary to include my source code in this post, all that my page does is show the results of previous meeting and the points difference between the two teams. If they have not met before it is obvious there will be no points differences to calculate hence the Division by zero error. So now that I gave you a bit of background is it possible you could help me?

Comment: Without code, I cannot help more than what I've said above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either make sure that divisions by zero are simply not possible (by doing some variable checks), or you could register a custom error handler to at least present the user with a pretty error message, see:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php